# replacing a CFL dimmer with an LED dimmer for recessed lighting

Tags: switch, led, installation, replacement

[image]I want to replace my old recessed lighting with new integrated LED recessed lighting.  My old dimmer switch specifically says for CFL.  The old dimmer has 2 black wires coming out of the back of it and they are hooked to 2 black wires in the wall.  My new dimmer (a Lutron)  has a green grounding wire and a copper and brass screws on the sides.  I have tried following instructions provided and there is power to the switch, but it does not go to the recessed lighting. (they do not work) - what am I missing?
The new dimmer I bought is a Lutron ACYL-153P-WH.  I had the ground connected and tried again with it disconnected and it the lights still don't work.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The ground wire may be the clue if you do not have a good ground the switch may not work, check the instructions, but that may be your problem.

Comment: OK, with dimmers, there is not a specific match between lamp type and dimmer type.  The old dimmers made only for incandescents are going to be hit-and-miss on newer bulbs... but generally newer dimmers made for CFLs are likely to play well with LEDs. 

So I would not replace the dimmer until you've tried it with LEDs and seen it fail.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box please?

Comment: Do the LEDs work with the old dimmer? (The distinction is more "newfangled lighting with drive electronics" vs. "old fashioned incandescent light bulbs that just get their filaments wired straight to 120VAC" than anything to do with the specifics of CFL vs. LED)